# Icon AND Text in UISegmentedController

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

> A segment can only have an image or a title; it can’t have both. There is no default image.

So says Apple in the [UISegmentedController Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html).

Has anyone come up with a generalized solution that allows you to have both an icon and text? I have a Segmented Control that has four segments. There are options for customizing the appearance of the control, but they only seem designed for a UISegmentedControl with two segments?

Ideas I'm kicking around:

1. Ditch the segmented control for four UIButtons and handle the "selected" state myself
2. Throw my hands up just go with text *or* icons.
3. Your suggestions...?

Comment: You could construct an image that has the title text in it using photoshop or some other drawing software.

Comment: Maybe, the UIButtons way is the best. You must handle the buttons, but it is not difficult. You only need a `for` statement (on the array that cointans your UIButton) and use the `isSelected` property of UIButton.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to try a third-party alternative such as [STSegmentedControl](https://github.com/SkyTrix/STSegmentedControl) (No relation, but I've used it, and it sounds like it will give you the flexibility you need without starting from scratch).

Comment: Thank you. It turns out that I need to do some more work on this to make it function exactly how I want. BUT, like you said, I don't have to start from scratch.

Answer (score 10):

You create a new image by drawing your current image into a context, draw the text you want,then use that combo image as the single segment image:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, YES, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Text first
[myString drawAtPoint:somePoint withFont:font];

// Images upside down so flip them 
CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, size.height);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);
CGContextDrawImage(context, (CGRect){ imagePoint, imageSize }, [myUIimage CGImage]);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
```

Comment: thanks for this snippet. I've turned it into a [UIImage category](https://gist.github.com/3801542), which I've found very useful: [https://gist.github.com/3801542](https://gist.github.com/3801542). It can be used like this `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageFromImage:uiImage] string:@"string" color:[UIColor whiteColor]];`

Comment: @somethingkindawierd (a) Thank you for sharing your category. (b) Can't we drop that right-square-bracket ']' after uiImage? Like this: [UIImage imageFromImage:uiImage string:@"string" color:[UIColor whiteColor]];

Comment: Thanks for posting the gist. FWIW, in the gist I think that MAX(expectedTextSize.height, image.size.width) should be MAX(expectedTextSize.height, image.size.height). Correct?

Comment: @mrkhingston yes I used square images so it didn't matter

Answer (score 0):

You can try my solution and modify it as you wish. Add some extensions:

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {
    enum EdgeAttribute {
        case leading, trailing
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    func insertAttributedText(_ text: NSAttributedString, atEdge edge: NSLayoutConstraint.EdgeAttribute, offset: CGFloat, preferredImageSize: CGSize?) -> UIImage {
        var imageSize = size
    
        if let size = preferredImageSize {
            imageSize = size
        }
    
        let textSize = text.size()
        let expectedBoundsWidth = textSize.width + imageSize.width + offset
        let expectedBoundsHeight = max(textSize.height, imageSize.height)
        let expectedBoundsSize = CGSize(width: expectedBoundsWidth, height: expectedBoundsHeight)
        let render = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: expectedBoundsSize)
    
        return render.image(actions: { _ in
            let textXPoint: CGFloat
            let imageXPoint: CGFloat
        
            switch edge {
            case .leading:
                textXPoint = 0
                imageXPoint = textSize.width + offset
            case .trailing:
                textXPoint = imageSize.width + offset
                imageXPoint = 0
            }
        
            let textYPoint: CGFloat = (expectedBoundsSize.height - textSize.height) / 2
            let imageYPoint: CGFloat = (expectedBoundsSize.height - imageSize.height) / 2
        
            text.draw(at: CGPoint(x: textXPoint, y: textYPoint))
            draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: imageXPoint, y: imageYPoint), size: imageSize))
        })
    }
}
```

Then configure your segmentedControl:

```
    let image = UIImage(systemName: "doc.plaintext")!.insertAttributedText(
        NSAttributedString(string: "Text"),
        atEdge: .leading,
        offset: 5,
        preferredImageSize: CGSize(width: 16, height: 12)
    )
     
    segmentedControl.insertSegment(with: image, at: 0, animated: false)
```